# How do I convert a Decimal to Varchar with a specific format

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm using SQL Server 2008

I have just a decimal value as `137909.19` and I need to convert it to `varchar` with this format: `137,909.19`.

```
declare @myNumber decimal(15,2) = 137909.19

select CAST(@myNumber AS varchar(20)) -- Result: 137909.19
```

I have looked over several posts but I can't found the solution.

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try casting it as money.

```
declare @myNumber decimal(15,2) = 137909.19 
declare @myvalue varchar(20)

set @myvalue = convert(varchar, cast(@myNumber as money),1) 
PRINT @myvalue
```

output will be "137,909.19"

Comment: I changed the formatting from one of an error, to code so that you get syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT FORMAT(@myNumber,'N2', 'en-US')
```

Comment: FORMAT() is available only in 2012 and later not in 2008